# Flatten Nested Json for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a column in pandas data frame, which stores json. Below is the json format.

```
"{'kookooOutboundResponse': {'NewCall': {'event': 'NewCall', 'cid': 
   '09528005139', 'called_number': '914071326527', 'sid':
  '7919156078536741', 'outbound_sid': '7919156078536741', 'circle': 
  'UTTAR PRADESH (W) and UTTARAKHAND', 'operator': 'Reliance', 
  'cid_type': '91', 'cid_e164': '+919528005139', 'request_time': '2019-06-17 
  20:59:43', 'cid_country': '91', '__proto__': {}}, 'GotDTMF': {'event': 
  'GotDTMF', 'sid': '7919156078536741', 'data': '1', 'cid': '09528005139', 
  'called_number': '914071326527', 'request_time': '2019-06-17 21:00:27', 
  '__proto__': {}}, 'Hangup': {'event': 'Hangup', 'sid': '7919156078536741', 
  'process': 'none', 'total_call_duration': '47', 'cid': '09528005139', 
 'called_number': '914071326527', 'request_time': '2019-06-17 21:00:30', 
 '__proto__': {}}}}"
```

I need to flatten the json, so that I have all the keys as the column & store values in the respective column name.

Comment: It's not valid json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `concat` and [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
data= "{'kookooOutboundResponse': {'NewCall': {'event': 'NewCall', 'cid': '09528005139', 'called_number': '914071326527', 'sid': '7919156078536741', 'outbound_sid': '7919156078536741', 'circle': 'UTTAR PRADESH (W) and UTTARAKHAND', 'operator': 'Reliance', 'cid_type': '91', 'cid_e164': '+919528005139', 'request_time': '2019-06-17 20:59:43', 'cid_country': '91', 'proto': {}}, 'GotDTMF': {'event': 'GotDTMF', 'sid': '7919156078536741', 'data': '1', 'cid': '09528005139', 'called_number': '914071326527', 'request_time': '2019-06-17 21:00:27', 'proto': {}}, 'Hangup': {'event': 'Hangup', 'sid': '7919156078536741', 'process': 'none', 'total_call_duration': '47', 'cid': '09528005139', 'called_number': '914071326527', 'request_time': '2019-06-17 21:00:30', 'proto': {}}}}"
```

---

```
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[data, data]})

L = [json_normalize(ast.literal_eval(x)['kookooOutboundResponse']) for x in df['col']]
df1 = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True)
print (df1)
  NewCall.event  NewCall.cid NewCall.called_number       NewCall.sid  \
0       NewCall  09528005139          914071326527  7919156078536741   
1       NewCall  09528005139          914071326527  7919156078536741   

  NewCall.outbound_sid                     NewCall.circle NewCall.operator  \
0     7919156078536741  UTTAR PRADESH (W) and UTTARAKHAND         Reliance   
1     7919156078536741  UTTAR PRADESH (W) and UTTARAKHAND         Reliance   

  NewCall.cid_type NewCall.cid_e164 NewCall.request_time  ...  GotDTMF.cid  \
0               91    +919528005139  2019-06-17 20:59:43  ...  09528005139   
1               91    +919528005139  2019-06-17 20:59:43  ...  09528005139   

  GotDTMF.called_number GotDTMF.request_time Hangup.event        Hangup.sid  \
0          914071326527  2019-06-17 21:00:27       Hangup  7919156078536741   
1          914071326527  2019-06-17 21:00:27       Hangup  7919156078536741   

  Hangup.process Hangup.total_call_duration   Hangup.cid Hangup.called_number  \
0           none                         47  09528005139         914071326527   
1           none                         47  09528005139         914071326527   

   Hangup.request_time  
0  2019-06-17 21:00:30  
1  2019-06-17 21:00:30  

[2 rows x 24 columns]
```